# Unable to locate package pptd

Tags: pptp

I Have Ubuntu system release as below:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:        11.04
Codename:       natty
```

I tried to install pptp using command:

```
sudo apt-get install pptd
```

and I get this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pptd
```

I use command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This what I get many error like this:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse Sources 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
```

this is what written in source list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main
```

any body can help

Comment: You're getting all these issues because 11.04 reached its end-of-life date in early 2012. You need to upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `pptpd`? However, as @Zacharee1 pointed out, I don't think the Natty software repositories are operational anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it failed to fetch because Ubuntu Natty has reached EOL(End Of Life). So you need to update your source list to install this package.

But I was wondering how **saucy** came into your source list while you were using natty. This is misleading. Taking in account that your system is Natty, follow the steps updating your source list so you can install packages from old repo archive.

1. Backup current source list.

   mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
2. create a new source list

   nano /etc/apt/sources.list
3. Paste the following in it.

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe multiverse

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
4. Exit the editor

   Ctrl +x

   Y
5. Now update

   sudo apt-get update
6. Install your required package. Thats it.

Comment: saucy add by me when I'm trying to find solution